# os.path.abspath(__file__) give invalid locaiton and adds extra \'s to the file path

Tags: python, windows, path

I am working on a program that will edit all local files ending in a csv extension. When I call the location of the directory and then change directory I get an error. The error is due to extra \'s being added to the path. How can I call the path without these extra \'s?

I've looked around and there are similar issues but every example I see is for a hard written location and not a movable one.

```
import os
import glob
import sys


path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
extension = '.csv'
os.chdir(os.path.abspath(__file__))
result = glob.glob('*'.format(extension))
print(path)
print(result)
```

Comment: what is the value of `__file__`? you can't change the current directory to a file, since it's not a directory. which is what `os.chdir(os.path.abspath(__file__))` will do.

Comment: You should add the stacktrace as well.

Comment: print(path) outputs C:\Users\AMP User\Desktop\Programs\New folder\Auto Edit.py

Comment: tried os.chdir(os.path.abspath(__file__)) and it has the same output

Comment: `os.chdir()` needs a `directory` not a `file` which is what you are giving it. try changing `os.chdir(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path))`

Comment: when I print os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path)) I get none as the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`os.chdir()` needs a directory not a file which is what you are giving it. try changing `os.chdir(os.path.abspath(__file__))` to `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path))`

```
import os
import glob
import sys

__file__ = 'test.txt'

path = os.path.abspath(__file__)
print(path)
extension = '.csv'
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(path))
result = glob.glob('*'.format(extension))
print(path)
print(result)
```

Comment: What does `print(os.path.dirname(path))` output?

Comment: You can remove `replace(r'\\\\', '\\')` because `abspath` already collapses repeated backslashes where it's appropriate, i.e. everywhere except if exactly two are used for a UNC root.

Comment: You're right, I had forgotten that was in there and didn't delete it.